# Is writing a txt file in php faster (lighter) than updating a mysql table? (for websites stats)

Tags: php, mysql

I'm creating some small statistics for my sites (no, I don't want to use anlitycs, metrica or other) and first of all i need the ip's of the visitors, to know if it's a new visit or the same visitor visiting another page.

The IPs can be saved in a mysql table, and deleted every two hours (a visitor hardly spends more than two hours in my sites) not to overload the table unnecessarily.

But then for each visit you have to look in the table if the ip is already present, to understand if it's a new visit or a new page, and based on the result you have to update other tables, a continuous back and forth of connections and changes on mysql tables.

Maybe not the fastest, lightest way to do this...

It could be easier to save the ip's in a file, with the function, file_put_contents, create a new file every hour and delete the oldest three hours (for each site).
But to open the file at each visit to check if an ip has already been added, I'm afraid it's a heavy and tiring operation for the server, maybe even longer and more tiring than opening a new connection and modify a mysql table?

I could also just add all the ip's at each visit (even if they are duplicates) to the file and then check if the ip's are duplicates with a crontab every midnight, but creating a constantly updated file with all the ip's of my visitors could be heavier than constantly updating mysql? (In my server currently there can be even 500,000 page views in a day).

And as a final folly... could I use apache log files? Could a php script access them and process and load my data into a db via a crontab?
(even if I would prefer not to use them because with a php script in each page of my site I could detect other parameters or data not present in apache logs)

-----------------------Update--------------

I immediately blamed mysql, but some of the answers make me doubt.

This is my code, it's pretty simple and basic, it seemed unnecessary to show it, but okay, do you see anything that could be clogging mysql and and overloading the server?

```
    <?
//echo str_replace('www.', '', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']).' - '.$_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"].' - '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

function get_domain($url)
{
  $pieces = parse_url($url);
  $domain = isset($pieces['host']) ? $pieces['host'] : $pieces['path'];
  if (preg_match('/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9][a-z0-9\-]{1,63}\.[a-z\.]{2,6})$/i', $domain, $regs)) {
    return $regs['domain'];
  }
  return false;
}

//echo 'domain: '.get_domain($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);

$is_engine = 0;

foreach(file('function_global/pu_stats/engines.txt') as $engine) {
    if($engine != '' && str_contains(trim(strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])), trim(strtolower($engine)))){
        $is_engine = 1;
        //if($is_engine == 1)
        //break;
    }
}

$db_host = "localhost";
$db_user = "";
$db_password = "";
$db_name = 'pu_stats';

$mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

    /* check connection */
    if($mysqli->connect_errno){
        die("Connect failed: %s\n, ".$mysqli->connect_error);
    }


if($is_engine == 0){
    //temp ip
    $ip_found = 0;

    //inserisco nuovi ip in tabella ip
    $query_pu_stats_ip = "SELECT ip FROM pu_stats_ip WHERE ip='".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ."' AND website='".get_domain($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])."'";
    $result_ip = $mysqli->query($query_pu_stats_ip);
        if($result_ip->num_rows < 1){
            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO pu_stats_ip (ip, website, ins) values ('".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', '".get_domain($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])."', '".time()."')");
        }else{
            $ip_found = 1;
        }
    //---------------


    $query_pu_stats = "SELECT day FROM pu_stats WHERE day='".date("d-m-Y", time())."' AND website='".get_domain($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])."'";
    $result = $mysqli->query($query_pu_stats);
        if($ip_found == 0){
            if($result->num_rows < 1){
                $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO pu_stats (day, website, visits, pages_views) values ('".date("d-m-Y", time())."', '".get_domain($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])."', '1', '1')");
            }else{
                $mysqli->query("UPDATE pu_stats SET visits = visits + 1, pages_views = pages_views + 1 WHERE day='".date("d-m-Y", time())."' AND website='".get_domain($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])."'");
            }
        }elseif($ip_found == 1){
            if($result->num_rows < 1){
                $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO pu_stats (day, website, pages_views) values ('".date("d-m-Y", time())."', '".get_domain($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])."', pages_views + 1)");
            }else{
                $mysqli->query("UPDATE pu_stats SET pages_views = pages_views + 1 WHERE day='".date("d-m-Y", time())."' AND website='".get_domain($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])."'");
            }
        }

 /*   
    //lingue
    $pu_stats_lang = locale_accept_from_http($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']);
    if($pu_stats_lang != ''){
    $query_pu_stats_lang = "SELECT day FROM pu_stats_lang WHERE day='".date("d-m-Y", time())."' AND website='".get_domain($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])."' AND lang='".$pu_stats_lang."'";
    $result_lang = $mysqli->query($query_pu_stats_lang);
        if($result_lang->num_rows < 1){
            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO pu_stats_lang (day, website, lang, lang_n) values ('".date("d-m-Y", time())."', '".get_domain($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])."', '".$pu_stats_lang."', '1')");
        }else{
            $mysqli->query("UPDATE pu_stats_lang SET lang_n = lang_n + 1 WHERE day='".date("d-m-Y", time())."' AND website='".get_domain($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])."' AND lang='".$pu_stats_lang."'");
        }
    }

    //browser
    $getbrowser = get_browser(null, true);
    if($getbrowser['browser'] != ''){
    $query_pu_stats_browser = "SELECT day FROM pu_stats_browser WHERE day='".date("d-m-Y", time())."' AND website='".get_domain($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])."' AND browser='".$getbrowser['browser']."'";
    $result_browser = $mysqli->query($query_pu_stats_browser);
        if($result_browser->num_rows < 1){
            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO pu_stats_browser (day, website, browser, browser_n) values ('".date("d-m-Y", time())."', '".get_domain($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])."', '".$getbrowser['browser']."', '1')");
        }else{
            $mysqli->query("UPDATE pu_stats_browser SET browser_n = browser_n + 1 WHERE day='".date("d-m-Y", time())."' AND website='".get_domain($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])."' AND browser='".$getbrowser['browser']."'");
        }
    }

    //os
    if($getbrowser['platform'] != ''){
    $query_pu_stats_os = "SELECT day FROM pu_stats_os WHERE day='".date("d-m-Y", time())."' AND website='".get_domain($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])."' AND os='".$getbrowser['platform']."'";
    $result_os = $mysqli->query($query_pu_stats_os);
        if($result_os->num_rows < 1){
            $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO pu_stats_os (day, website, os, os_n) values ('".date("d-m-Y", time())."', '".get_domain($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])."', '".$getbrowser['platform']."', '1')");
        }else{
            $mysqli->query("UPDATE pu_stats_os SET os_n = os_n + 1 WHERE day='".date("d-m-Y", time())."' AND website='".get_domain($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'])."' AND os='".$getbrowser['platform']."'");
        }
    }
*/
}//fine if engine

//old ips
$mysqli->query("DELETE FROM pu_stats_ip WHERE ins < ".(time() - 10800));

//contatore tutte visualizzazioni motori e non
$query_pu_stats_tot = "SELECT day FROM pu_stats_tot_visits WHERE day='".date("d-m-Y", time())."'";
$result_tot = $mysqli->query($query_pu_stats_tot);
        if($result_tot->num_rows < 1){
            if($is_engine == 0){
                $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO pu_stats_tot_visits (day, visits, ".$site_niche.") values ('".date("d-m-Y", time())."', '1', '1')");
            }elseif($is_engine == 1){
                $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO pu_stats_tot_visits (day, engines) values ('".date("d-m-Y", time())."', '1')");
            }
        }else{
            if($is_engine == 0){
                $mysqli->query("UPDATE pu_stats_tot_visits SET visits = visits + 1, ".$site_niche." = ".$site_niche." + 1 WHERE day='".date("d-m-Y", time())."'");
            }elseif($is_engine == 1){
                $mysqli->query("UPDATE pu_stats_tot_visits SET engines = engines + 1 WHERE day='".date("d-m-Y", time())."'");
            }
        }

/* close connection */
    $mysqli->close();

?>
```

the commented out parts are other parameters, like browser, language etc, commented out because if I enable them the server goes on fire.

I use mysqli because the rest of my sites use pdo, just not to mess up, anyway i have to change database.

engines.txt is just this:

```
bot
curl
spider
python
crawl
http
engine
```

Just to understand, my server is small, 2 processors 4gb of ram...

Comment: You'd have to simulate it to try and test but I strongly suspect the database is probably going to be quicker overall. And far easier to actually collect the statistics from afterwards...you have to consider that as well. Are you actually experiencing a performance problem currently, or is this purely speculative?

Comment: P.S. If you delete each piece of data after 2 hours (which I think is what you were saying), then how do you ever collect any meaningful statistics anyway? Or do you copy it all somewhere else first?

Comment: @ADyson actually I've already started, with mysql, my server hasn't exploded yet, but the load has already significantly increased... and since I'd like to add to my statistics other parameters, I'd surely send the server in crisis...

Comment: @ADyson Checking if an ip is present or not would only serve to understand whether to update the visitors file/table or pages viewed file/table

Comment: I'll say, although I know you've ruled it out, that this is one reason why people use 3rd-party analytics services. Of course it's possible you've simply written the code in a very inefficient way, but we cannot tell because there's no code in the question. Or it could be you need a better server to cope with the extra queries, or perhaps you would indeed get better performance with a file-based system (but I really doubt it personally).

Comment: 500k page views a day are about 6 per second. MySQL should be able to do 10.000 simple queries/s (e.g. looking up and inserting via a primary key) without any trouble. If your server gets into crisis with this, you may want to share some details about your implementation and/or do some benchmarking to check where you lose throughput.

Answer (score 1):

A "file open" is far more costly than doing another well-indexed database action.

Scanning through 500K rows in a file is far slower than a well-indexed database action.

On the other hand, some db operations are slower than file operations.

"look in the table if the ip is already present, to understand if it's a new visit or a new page" -- That should be a single query that takes under 10ms in a db.  In a file, it is proportional to the number of rows in the file.  That is, the dedupping can be done at the same time as the inserting.  And, if desired, bump a counter.

500K/day = 6/second.  Come back with performance questions when you get to 100/second.

Sure, Apache + PHP + MySQL sounds complex.  But keep in mind that that 'stack' (or something similar) is the backbone of a large percentage of the web sites in existence today.

Midnight cron jobs are a hassle.  If they are done 'wrong', data is lost or counts are inflated.  And the real nightmare (probably would not happen for your task) is when one cron does not finish before the next one starts.  That's a meltdown.  (OK, it can be coded around, but you have to think to do it.)

Purging old data?  If you have millions of rows, then partition the table so you can simply do `DROP PARTITION`.  (OK, that needs cron.)

Yes, scan the Apache log files.  They can be messy to parse, but I have seen a company with thousands of Apache servers where the logs were parsed and the data was fed into huge databases.

An old trick is to have a 1x1 pixel image on the page.  When it is loaded, a line goes into the Apache log.  The newer trick is to have an AJAX call to send info directly to PHP, thereby avoiding the log and its parsing.  This might involve "onLoad".

Don't give up on MySQL too fast.  There are several performance techniques that are not obvious to beginners.  Some of them speed things up by an order of magnitude.